# What does as mean here

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Canned baked beans are used as a convenience food. They may be eaten hot or cold straight from the can **as** they are fully cooked.

What does **as** mean here? Does it simply means **because**? ,to rephrase it;

> They may be eaten hot or cold straight from the can **because** they are **already** fully cooked.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if you replace "as" with "because", the global meaning remains the same.

However, in my opinion "because" would be more relevant for a cause-effect relation.

Here, the fact that your beans are fully cooked is not a direct cause of the fact you can eat them hot or cold, it's rather a condition among other possible ones. It's fully cooked, therefore you can eat them the way you want, but it could be for any other reason.

Comment: Yes; "as" can stand for "because" or "since". This is perhaps more idiomatic in UK English than in everyday US/Canadian usage.

Comment: I agree. I am not at all sure what distinction is being made here, but in British English I doubt there is any real difference in meaning in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is right; "as" is also used for giving the reason for something (in the sense of "because").

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.  **AS** could be used as an adverb, conjunction, and preposition. It more preferable.

Your context, we could use words like

#### Because

Because is more common than as and since, both in writing and speaking. When we use because we are focusing on the reason.

#### When

We can use when to introduce a single completed event that takes place in the middle of a longer activity or event. In these cases, we usually use a continuous verb in the main clause to describe the background event.

#### As

We can use **as** to introduce two events happening at the same time. After **as**, we can use a simple or continuous form of the verb. The continuous form emphasises an action that interrupts or occurs during the progress of another action.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)